# WPN-XM support for different PHP versions

Tags: php, wpn-xm

Does WPN-XM come with PHP 5.6.17? If not, is it easy to install this version? I need it to track down a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does WPN-XM come with PHP 5.6.17?

No, the lastest release is WPN-XM v0.8.6 and the Installers for PHP56 ship  5.6.12.

> If not, is it easy to install this version?

Yes, its easy to install another PHP version.

4 steps:

1. download for instance the [Lite Setup (WPNXM-0.8.6-Lite-Setup-php56-w64.exe)](https://github.com/WPN-XM/WPN-XM/releases/download/v0.8.6/WPNXM-0.8.6-Lite-Setup-php56-w64.exe)
2. after, installation rename the existing PHP folder `bin\php` to `bin\php-5.6.12`
3. download PHP: http://wpn-xm.org/get.php?s=php-x64&v=5.6.17
4. extract the content of the downloaded PHP zip file into `bin\php`

Done.